# Why is there a kmeans and kmeans_plusplus function in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I want to use the kmeans method in the scikit-learn library and I was reading the documentation to see if there was a parameter to use kmeans++. It turns out that this is the default behavior. However, there is also a kmeans_plusplus method that is just kmeans++ and has no option for random initialization. What is the purpose of having two functions that accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the purpose of having two functions is to provide users with flexibility and clarity in their choice of initialization method. The default behavior of K-Means uses the k-means++ method, which is a smart initialization technique that aims to select initial cluster centers in a way that improves the convergence of the algorithm and leads to better clustering results. On the other hand, the `kmeans_plusplus` function specifically exposes the k-means++ method without the option for random initialization, allowing users to explicitly use this method if desired.